# Posterior inference in GAM. Help with example + reading material

Tags: r, generalized-additive-model

In this blog post:

http://www.fromthebottomoftheheap.net/2016/12/15/simultaneous-interval-revisited/

The author shows very nicely how to find a simultaneous confidence interval for a smooth.

I have done it too for my model, however I then went ahead and included a new covariate in my regression, so its now

```
y ~ f(x) + plant
```

where plant is the factor.

Now when I run vcov and coef, gam will also give me those estimates concerning "plant". Anybody know how I can now get that 95 % confidence band, as done in the blog post? Should I just remove all the coefficients in coef and vcov that correspond to the factor?

And since I clearly don't understand it well enough, what's some good reading material for posterior simulation in gam?